# autotools/cmake advanced usage wrt static vs. dynamic linking

Tags: build, cmake, autotools, libtool

I have a somewhat advanced self-maintained build system 
 that I'm interested in changing to autotools or cmake.

The caveat is the "somewhat advanced" part of getting feature parity.

Here is what concerns me.

By default, we build "libraries" both static and dynamic, and install both. 
 When looking for libraries to link to, we search, first for dynamic, then static.

However we have a useful knob called build_standalone.

It does two things:
  - For libraries, it builds only the static library 
    Somewhat like libtool "convenience libraries" but they do get installed.

- For imports (from libraries and programs), it searches first for the static 
  library (which always exists for stuff we build, but maybe not for stuff we don't)).

  Importers cannot precisely specify which libraries should be linked statically, 
  but we are ok with that.

  Is parity achievable in this regard with libtool or cmake?
  How?

Thank you,
 - Jay

Comment: On first glance, I'd tempted to say it is possible with both build systems. You have to follow the philosophy of the build system. Usually you must adjust how the build system handles thinks. Otherwise you have clumsy workarounds. BTW, I wouldn't port a project to Autotools nowadays. It's development is stalling, they have difficulties finding maintainers for their tools.

Comment: @usr1234567, sorry for the late reply; as someone with more than a little time invested in the autotools, I'm sad to hear this, but such is the way technology goes. What do you see as technology that will displace it?

Answer (score 0):

With regard to *creating* both static and shared libraries, this can be accomplished quite easily within `configure.ac`:

```
...
LT_INIT
...
```

[This](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/LT_005fINIT.html) enables shared libraries by default and static libraries if they don't conflict with shared.

As for linking to static vs. shared libraries when both are present, you must add the necessary annotations to your `Makefile.am`. For example, if you have

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = foo.c foo.h
bin_PROGRAMS = bar qux
bar_SOURCES = bar.c
qux_SOURCES = qux.c
```

and you want to

- link `bar` dynamically to `libfoo`
- link `qux` statically to `libfoo`

then you can:

```
bar_LDADD = libfoo.la
qux_LDADD = libfoo.la
qux_LDFLAGS = -static
```

Comment: One thing I was not clear about though, is the build system only ever compiles everything once -- PIC -- and then makes static archives from those -- and of course dynamic .so. The double compile that many systems want to do is quite unpleasant and unnecessary to me, it is a double build time for a possible slight optimization.

Comment: @JayK, I'm confused. Does the above solution cause double compilation on your system? On my system, each source file is compiled only once.